# MPU6050 or GY521/HMC5883 chips are burnt for no reason

Tags: arduino-pro-mini

I been trying to interface MPU6050 and HMC5883 with an Arduino Pro Mini/Nano. I²C scanner works just fine and identifies the device with no issues. I let the I²C scanner run like for 5 minutes and I see fumes coming out of the chips and sometimes the Arduino itself is burnt. I tried pull up resistors 2.2k, 7k without any luck. Has anyone got any inputs to this issue. Really frustrating to spend a weekend on this :(

To rule out the possibility of 5V supply causing the burn out I tried 3.3V from Nano and made promini 3.3V from 5V. Please see the pictures below.

Arduino Nano 3.3v was used to power up the I²C.

[image: Arduino Nano Circuit].

[image: Pro Mini Circuit].

Pro Mini jumper was desoldered from 5V to 3.3V to see if the I²C chips are saved from being burnt. In both these setup voltage accross the I²C chip was measured and it was 3.3V.

Still no luck!

If you guys are to make the same circuit how would you do it and where would you get the components from? I must be doing something wrong and hope we together can figure it out.

Components are bought from eBay and the links are here.
GY521 = goo.gl/Y4aDph 
HMC5883 = goo.gl/DfrC9l
Arduino Nano = goo.gl/CaAykI 
PROMINI = goo.gl/79PVOM

**This is some background of why this issue resolution is so important to me:**
Just give you a backgroud of why I am doing this: I am building a quadcopter myself. Infact built one using GY80, but the module was expensive also it eventually got burnt out for the same reason mentioned above. Here is the first successful test flight of my first quadcopter goo.gl/rn6xWG (add https:// since I am rookie there is limitation on how many links I can post). If I can make the same thing work using GY521 and HMC5883 it would be awesome and cheaper.

Update on 08/11 @12:45 PM CST
I think it is because of the Pro Mini, I²C chips are getting fried. When using Nano, I think it is because of the voltage level difference between the SDA/SCL lines causing the problem. With Pro Mini tripped for 3.3V, I was not able to see any serial data from the chip too. To end all these I placed an order for 3.3V 8 MHz Pro Mini from amazon goo.gl/FjgTGj Let see how that goes.

Comment: Please post your wiring, or a photo of what you are doing, or both. Certainly the chips should not let out smoke.

Comment: `burnt for no reason` - chips don't burn for "no reason". There is a reason, you just haven't found it yet.

Comment: Arduino Nano/PROMINI, A4->SDA, A5->SCL, VCC to VCC, GND -> GND. Simple wiring on a bread board. I will send the picture later once i set up the circuit again.

Comment: The MPU6050 is a 3.3v device. Make sure you don't power it using 5v. Also make sure you don't connect the pull-ups to 5v, but to 3.3v. Also make sure there are no other breakouts on the I2C line that have pull-up resistors to 5v. Also [disable the internal pull-ups inside the arduino](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/how-disable-internal-arduino-atmega-pullups-sda-and-scl-i2c-bus)

Comment: Here is the diagram db.tt/4ocbNOYW. Without pullup resistors and trying the GY521 or HMC5883 alone is burning the chip. GY521 or HMC5883 I am using is a 3-5V variant should have been working just fine. GY521 = goo.gl/Y4aDph HMC5883 = goo.gl/DfrC9l      
Arduino Nano = goo.gl/CaAykI PROMINI = goo.gl/79PVOM –  Mohamed 2 mins ago   edit

Comment: Also @Gerben thanks for the info. I will try disabling the pullup resistors and see if it is working without any issues. Wonder how many more Arduinos/GY521 are left to try this out. Will Keep you posted.

Comment: That won't do much good if you are powering the devices with 5v like you show in the (tiny) diagram.

Comment: so If the promini is made 3.3v 8MHz from the 5V 16MHz, should it just work fine? or if I power the I2C devices from the 3.3v pin of the the Nano? I will try both ways and let you know. @Gerben I am reverting the pullup resistor changes from the wire library for now then.

Comment: It shouldn't be getting hot if you are only using 3.3 V. Can you please measure the Vcc into the HMC5883 and check it is 3.3 V?

Comment: I checked that it was 3.3V. No chip was getting hot like real hot but i can see fumes at times from the HMC5883 or GY521 for that matter. This last test i did no fumes happened but it fried the chips. If you masters are to make such a circuit how would you do it and where would you get the components from?

Comment: If I were in your shoes I would use my multimeter to measure the current going into the accelerometer. It should only be a few milliamps.

Comment: Now that the chip is burnt I need to solder up a new HMC5883 and see the current.  Will get back by tomorrow once I am back from work.  So if the current is higher what does it mean and what should be the conclusion.

Comment: Chips don't burn for no reason. Incorrect wiring could be one. Incorrect resistors. Voltage too high. And if the current was high I would be wondering **why** it is high.

Comment: Okay.  Let's think simple here.  5V Arduino powering the chip from 3.3v pin, why would you expect it to burn up.  I tried more than 10 Arduinos and i2c chips. Whole point of this open source chips is that it is plug and play.  May be because these are cheap knock off Arduinos and i2c chips one reason for this unpredictability.

Comment: Do the chips even tolerate 5V logic??

Comment: @Avamander Even used 3.3V power supply but it was still burning up the chips.

Comment: @Mohamed I did not ask about power supply. Do the I²C chips tolerate 5V I²C? Try dividing the voltage so that the chip gets 3.3V power and 3.3V logic.

Comment: @Avamander But how is it different from dedicated 3.3V for both Arduino and I²C?

Comment: @Mohamed I²C is a digital communication protocol. That means as digital data is 0 and 1s, 0 is 0V and 1 is the supply voltage, for 5V Arduino it is 5V. If you communicate with a chip that does not tolerate higher voltage logic, chips burn. That means 5V has to be turned into 3V in all places it could go in.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Fixed the issue with a dedicated 3.3V power supply.  I2C scanner is running for 30 minutes with no issues so far.